# How to automate image captcha?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to automate captcha in my registration page but there is no any command is found to me. Also trying to search on google but there is no any proper and exact way is given.everyone circulating one thing round and round. so please tell me possibility to automate captcha code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'automate'? You want to just check if there is captcha? You want to check that if you do not solve captcha user will not be registered?

Comment: No No . i just want to select suitable image from captcha option and then go forward to next step.

Comment: Please review your question to ask it more clearly. Also provide the links you found on google that are related to your problem, so we can understand it better.

Comment: sure. i am new on stack overflow. so currently i am learning mode on stack. also please give me suggestion regarding my question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve captcha. I mean this is really difficult to do because captcha was invented to protect against automation and bots.

If you want to check flow of registering, you must build 'debug' version of your app without captcha, or with captcha and with 'backdoor' so if you solve captacha or select e.g. first image, app allow you to register new user.

Comment: ok. thanks. But is possible to automate number captcha. eg. 2+3=5 this way answer. is it possible mack??

Comment: Captcha should be designed in a way that you cannot solve it using selenium. If you have captcha 2+3=? then 2+3 is probably an image so you will need to download image and use some kind of OCR for it. Long story short you cannot automate captacha and if you can just delete it from your website because is useless.

Comment: Thanks mack. Now i am understand the scope of captcha on selenium webdriver

Comment: If that answers your question please accept my answer.